# Matlab - 3D view with contrast DICOM

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am looking for a way to display the constrast of my dicom files when I render them in 3D.
Basically, when I am using one image, the contrast is fine :

```
i = dicomread(t);
imshow(i)
```

But I am building a 3D matrix using `patch` to render it and the contrast disapear once drawn (it uses the contour instead of the intensity although my images are stacked into a 3D matrix using `dicomread`)

Is there any way to plot in 3D using the voxel intensity instead of `patch` ?

Comment: Google the term "volume rendering"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following file from the FEX [vol3d-v2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2).

Comment: The result is quite low. [viewer 3D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21993-viewer3d) is nice but I wanted to know HOW he managed to get such a contrast...